# Unexpected not workable download button

Tags: html, pdf, button, download

I have the following  code based others tutorials (look at the picture):
When I run the code through the browser, the button is appeared but when I click on it the pdf does not downloaded (or appeared to other html page).I have checked if there is any problem with the file link but when I run it through browser is appeared to browser properly. I must note that this code is included to php file ( for example file.php).[CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6QXX.jpg)

HTML:

```
<button class="etc etc">
   <a href="itdb/a.pdf"></a>
   <i class="fa fa-download"></i>Katabaste Odygies
</button>
```

Comment: Hi Ronin - just following up. Was your question answered satisfactorily? If there is more I can help with, please add a comment below my answer, or edit your question to clarify what else you want to know. Otherwise, it would be great if you could choose a "best answer" (by clicking the checkmark beside the answer) to close out the question. If no answer provided helpful information, please add your own answer and select that as the best answer. *(You won't get any points for doing so, but that will close out the question.)* Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your anchor tag to look like this:

```
<button class="etc etc">
   <a href="itdb/a.pdf">
      <i class="fa fa-download"></i>Katabaste Odygies
   </a>
</button>
```

When people click the `<i>` tag, it is not inside the `<a>` so the download is not being triggered.

Also, you are referencing the file incorrectly for a web server.

Comment: I change the code like the previous answer :<button class="w3-button w3-light-grey w3-padding-large w3-section">
<a href="file://192.168.1.147/wamp64/www/itdb/a.pdf">
 <i class="fa fa-download"></i> Κατεβάστε Οδηγίες
 </a>
 </button>
 </p> .Now the problem is that when write the browser the file address the pdf is opened but when I press the button through the html button the pdf file does not open. Any ideas why??

Comment: Totally I modify the code as follow: <p>
 <a class="w3-button w3-light-grey w3-padding-large w3-section" href="file://192.168.1.147/wamp64/a.pdf" download>
     <span>Κατεβάστε Οδηγίες </span>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-download"></i>
 </a>
 </p>.Now the problem is that the link is opened through edge but not through mozila

Comment: Make your href like I put in my code: `<a href="itdb/a.pdf">`. The way you are doing it uses the Windows file system to locate the file, not the webserver. The way I did says: *"Starting in the folder with the document containing this HTML (index.html?), look for a folder called* ***itdb*** *and inside that a file called* ***a.pdf***. *Open the file* ***a.pdf*** *"*

Comment: Totally the code that works for me in all browsers is the follow: <p>
 <a class="w3-button w3-light-grey w3-padding-large w3-section" role="button" href="http://192.168.2.149:8076/a.pdf" href="file://192.168.2.149/wamp64/a.pdf" download="a.pdf">
  <i class="fa fa-download"></i> <span>Download the guide </span>&nbsp;
 </a>
 </p>

Comment: Glad it works for you. Seriously, though, you should do it the way I said. On a real website the `IP:Port/filename` will not work - but the other way should *always* work with every webserver. Not telling you to change what you have done, just suggesting you keep that in mind.